# Simple web-based icon editor

Tags: javascript, web-applications, image-manipulation

My web site uses 16 x 16 pixel icons (stored on the server as PNG files). I'd like to provide functionality for users of the site to edit these icons. My site already uses jQuery and jQuery UI, and I'm familiar with these, but any suggestions would be welcome.

**EDIT**

It seems that this is harder than I thought. I think I'm going to hold off trying to incorporate this functionality into the web site. But if anyone knows of a JavaScript icon/bitmap editor not already mentioned in the thread, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need: 100% javascript, great clean code.

https://mrcoles.com/favicon-creator/

Is the perfect start. With some work you can make it fit exactly as you need.

HIH,

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.jpie.net/ (requires PHP as well), it's the most advanced thing I've found but not too sure how much actual 'editing' users need to do (or can do on a 16px image...)

Comment: Thanks - I had a look at pixastic. At first glance it doesn't seem to be exactly what I want, and is still apparently in beta, but may the the closest that is available.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some inspiration here

http://www.rw-designer.com/online_icon_maker.php

I don't know of any licence-free, ready-to-go editor though.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at the code and see if I can make anything of it.